# I have changed max-age in liferay-web.xml file but its not reflecting in my server

Tags: filter, header, liferay

I have changed following properties...

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>Header Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.header.HeaderFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>url-regex-ignore-pattern</param-name>
            <param-value>.+/-/.+ </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>Cache-Control</param-name>
            <param-value>max-age=86400, public</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>Expires</param-name>
            <param-value>86400</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
```

I want `max-age` to be `86400` but its not getting reflected.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you restarted the server after changes?

Comment: yes . I restarted the server several times.